# jQuery: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting this error from this line of code

```
$( 'path.div-clickable' ).each(function( index ) {
   $( this ).addClass( 'polygon'+index );
});
```

**It throws error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1586)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2238)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2665)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.js:890)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2921)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:3031)
    at jQuery (jquery.js:98)
    at c (bootstrap.min.js:7)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:7)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:368)
```

**this function is called in a ajax request.**

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=" +
                "SELECT * FROM example", function(data) {

   addClassToPath();

});
```

> weird thing, the code works fine.

Comment: If you take out the `.each`, does it still throw an error? i.e. just `$('path.div-clickable')`. If it doesn’t, how about if you take out the body of the `each`? Can you narrow it down to a minimal change that causes an error to be thrown?

Comment: Yes, in both situations (without the `.each` or without the body of the `each`) still throws the same error.

Comment: How did you narrow down the error to the lines with `$('path.div-clickable')`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to run a sql query from a query string. This is called SQL INJECTION!

Comment: Is ther a tag named `path`?? Is this SVG?

Comment: @ibrahim Yes the tag named `path`is a svg and the class `polygon`is added correctly. @AHBagheri I know this query string is SQL Injection, is just for local purpose, not production code.

Comment: Are you sure you got the right code? Look at the three last lines of the error! It is related to bootstrap with some links (`a` tags). Maybe you have an anchor `href='##..'` or `href='#...#...'` or something that isn't a valid ID selector!

Comment: @ibrahim Can't believe it, was for a `href='#id'` instead of `href="#id"`, how it can be? Thanks man!.

Comment: @AlfreCano Is it still not working???

Comment: @ibrahim Yes is working now! Thx!!